# PhantomJS / SlimerJS cannot click on canvas element

Tags: javascript, canvas, automation, phantomjs, slimerjs

I am trying to automate a canvas element on a website using PhantomJS or SlimerJS. I am having a hard time getting the canvas element to detect my click buttons. From the screen shots, I can tell that the mouse is hovering over the buttons, but it refuses to click on them.

```
var page = require('webpage').create()
page.viewportSize={width: 1280, height: 768};
var fs = require('fs');
page.open('http://www.soulofsoccer.com/app/',function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ //wait for canvas to load
        page.render('soccer/step1.png','png');
        page.sendEvent("click",50,718); //menu button

         //test to click a second time
        setTimeout(function(){
            page.sendEvent("click",50,718);
            page.render('soccer/test1.png','png');
        },1000);

        //final screenshot
        setTimeout(function(){
            page.render('soccer/test.png','png');
            //phantom.exit();
            //slimer.exit();
        },2000);

    },10000); //wait for canvas to load
});
```

Can someone please indicate to me where my error is?

PhantomJS version: 1.9.8
SlimerJS version: 0.9.5

Answer (score 1):

I've only managed to make it work in PhantomJS 2.0.

I've looked at the page. You have to first move to the position that you want to click on and only then click. There is a difference between mouse moving and setting the position directly with a click. It seems this page is pretty particular about first registering a mouse move and only then enable the click action.

```
page.render('test19_step1.png');
page.sendEvent("mousemove",50,718); //menu button

setTimeout(function(){
    page.sendEvent("click",50,718);
},1000);

setTimeout(function(){
    page.render('test19_test.png');
    phantom.exit();
},2000);
```

I suggest you use an abstraction for this:

```
function clickInCanvas(x, y, callback, delayBetween) {
    delayBetween = delayBetween || 50;
    page.sendEvent("mousemove", x, y);

    setTimeout(function(){
        page.sendEvent("click", x, y);
    }, delayBetween);

    setTimeout(callback, delayBetween*2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying so fast. Unfortunately, this only works sometimes. I can run the test multiple times and and it is not always the result.